# How to animate? Dripping/melting shape

Tags: after-effects

I wish to animate this logo. As first the rectangles appear (already figure out with shape masks and track matte) But then I want to make the "paint" drip off it and I can't figure out what method I should use. Im a newb at after effects and I mostly learn from tutorials but I can't find anything specific enough to help me. Please give me advice I witch direction should I look.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Animated shape layer would be my first choice. Draw the final shape of the dripping paint, turn on animation for that shape at the end, wind back to the beginning and edit the shape until it looks like how you want it to start, then preview the animation and tweak any intermediate frames as necessary.

**TL;DR**: animate it.